# What exactly does this mean?

Tags: xcode, macos

```
- (IBAction)theButton:(id)sender
   [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/"]];
}
```

I'm new and having trouble connecting this to a button in the main menu.
Can you explain what this stuff does?

Answer (score 1):

It is a method that, when called, will open a URL in the user's browser.

The `IBAction` is just a marker that allows XCode to know that this is an action, so it will let you link this to a button (or something similar) on a form in a Nib, so that when the button is clicked, the URL is loaded.

`[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/"]` creates a URL, fairly obviously.

You can get all the details on [NSWorkspace in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: What is the other stuff mean?